# Show that $pm(A) \ge \sum_{j=1}^k m(A_j)$, when $p \in \Bbb N$ and $x$ is in at most $p$ many of $A_k$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $A_1, \dots, A_k \subset \Bbb R^n$ be measurable sets and $A=\bigcup_{j=1}^k A_j$. Suppose that there exists $p \in \Bbb N$ such that every $x \in \Bbb R^n$ is in at most $p$ many of $A_1, \dots, A_k$. Show that $$pm(A) \ge \sum_{j=1}^k m(A_j).$$

I have that $$pm(A) = p \int \chi_A = \int p \chi_A \ge \int \sum_{j=1}^k \chi_{A_j} = \sum_{j=1}^k  \int \chi_{A_j} = \sum_{j=1}^k m(A_j)$$ but my question is that how do we get the inequality $\sum_{j=1}^k \chi_{A_j} \le p\chi_{A}$?

Answer (score 1):

From the definition of $\chi_{B}:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \left\{0,1\right\}$

$$\chi_{B}(x) = \begin{cases} 1, \textrm{ if } x\in B \\ 0, \textrm{ if } x\notin B\end{cases}$$

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. By assumption $x$ is in at most $p$ of the many $A_{1},...,A_{j}$. Denote $A_{i_{k}}$ with $\left\{i_{1},i_{2},..i_{m} \right\}\subset\left\{1,...,j\right\}$ the sets that satisfy that $x\in A_{i_{k}} \quad 1\leq k\leq m \leq p$

$$ \chi_{A_{j}} = 1 \textrm{ if } j\in \left\{i_{1},i_{2},..i_{m} \right\}$$

$$ \chi_{A_{j}} = 0 \textrm{ if } j\in \left\{1,...,k\right\} \setminus\left\{i_{1},i_{2},..i_{m} \right\}$$

Hence

$$\sum_{j=1}^{k} \chi_{A_{j}} = \sum_{j\notin\left\{i_{1},...,i_{m}\right\}} \chi_{A_{j}}+ \sum_{j\in\left\{i_{1},...,i_{m}\right\}} \chi_{A_{j}} = 0+m \leq  p$$

On the other hand

$$ x\in A_{i_{1}},...A_{i_{m}} \Longrightarrow x \in A = \bigcup_{j=1}^k A_j \Longrightarrow \chi_{A}=1$$

$$\sum_{j=1}^{k} \chi_{A_{j}} \leq  p\cdot 1  = p\chi_{A}$$